# Asymptotic expansion with stationary phase

Tags: asymptotics

I am reading Rudolf Haag's book on "Local Quantum Physics", and on page 89 he writes that the following function $f(t,\vec{x}) = \int \tilde{f}(\vec{p})\exp(i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-\epsilon_{\vec{p}}t))d^3p/(2\epsilon_{\vec{p}})$ ;$\epsilon_{\vec{p}} = \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$ $\tilde{f}$ is a smooth function, decreasing fast for $|\vec{p}| \to \infty$. The asymptotic form for large $|t|$ can be obtained by applying the method of stationary phase to the integral stated above. Since the phase $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{x}-\epsilon_{\vec{p}} t$ is rapdily varying as function of $\vec{p}$ when t (and possibly also $\vec{x}$ is large, the dominant contribution to the integral comes from the point: $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}(1-\vec{v}^2)^{-1/2}$; $\vec{v} = \vec{x}/t$.

where the phase is stationary. One finds the asymptotic expansion 
$$f(t,\vec{x}) = const. t^{-3/2}\exp(-im\gamma^{-1}t)(\gamma^{3/2}\tilde{f}(m\gamma v)+O(t^{-1}))$$

where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$.

I don't understand how to get the stationary phase approxiamtiom here in order to get the last asymptotic expansion for $f(t,\vec{x})$. Can anyone explain this to me?

In the wiki page on stationary phase:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation

there's no mention of stationary phase of three dimensional case or the general case, so that's why I am bit puzzled on how to make this calculation your help is appreciated.

Comment: Under section "See also" of the Wikipedia page you mentioned is a link to "Method of steepest descent". See especially "The asymptotic expansion in the case of a single non-degenerate saddle point" therein. Does this help?

Comment: @udrv it does seem to help. (Though I didn't know that I'll need Morse theory here).